# Look up an attribute from an instance

Tags: python, python-3.x

From Python in a Nutshell

> **Getting an attribute from an instance**
>
> When you use the syntax  `x.name`  to refer to an attribute of
>   instance  `x`  of class  `C` , the lookup proceeds in three steps:
>
> 1. *When  `name`  is found in  `C`  (or in one of  `C`’s ancestor classes) as the name of an overriding descriptor  `v`  (i.e., 
>      `type(v)`  supplies methods  `__get__` and  `__set__` )*
>
>    • *The value of  `x.name`  is the result of  `type(v).__get__(v, x, C)`*
> 2. Otherwise, when  `name`  is a key in  `x.__dict__`
>
>    • `x.name`  fetches and returns the value at  `x.__dict__['name']`
> 3. Otherwise,  `x.name`  delegates the lookup to  `x`’s class (according to the same two-step lookup used for  `C.name`, as just
>      detailed)
>
>    • *When a descriptor  `v`  is found, the overall result of the
>      attribute lookup is, again,  `type(v).__get__(v, x, C)`*
>
>    • When  a  nondescriptor  value  `v`   is  found,  the  overall 
>      result  of  the  attribute lookup is just  `v`
>
> When these lookup steps do not find an attribute, Python raises an  `AttributeError` exception. However, for lookups of  `x.name` , when  `C`  defines or inherits the special
>   method  `__getattr__` , Python calls  `C.__getattr__(x,'name')`  rather than raising
>   the exception. It’s then up to  `__getattr__`  to either return a suitable value or raise
>   the appropriate exception, normally  `AttributeError` .

1. Are step 1 and the first part of step 3 the same? If yes, why does the same step appear twice?
2. Do they both happen *"when `name` is found in `C` (or in one of `C`’s ancestor classes) as the name of an overriding descriptor  `v`"*?

---

> ```
> __getattribute__(self, name)
> ```
>
> At every request to access attribute `x.y`, Python calls
>   `x.__getattribute__('y')`, which must get and return the attribute
>   value or else raise `AttributeError`. The normal semantics of
>   attribute access (using `x.__dict__`, `C.__slots__`, `C`’s class
>   attributes, `x.__getattr__`) are all due to `object.__getattribute__`.
>   When class `C` overrides `__getattribute__`, it must implement all of
>   the attribute access semantics it wants to offer. Most often, the most
>   convenient way to implement attribute access semantics is by
>   delegating (e.g., calling `object.__getattribute__(self, ...)` as part
>   of the operation of your override of `__getattribute__`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are step 1 and the first part of step 3 the same? If yes, why the same step appear twice?

Step 1 requires both `__get__` and `__set__` (although actually, either `__set__` or `__delete__` along with `__get__` would trigger it). Step 3 happens unconditionally if the attribute isn't found through steps 1 or 2.

> Do they both happen "when  name is found in  C (or in one of  C’s ancestor classes) as the name of an overriding descriptor  v"?

No. An "overriding descriptor" triggers step 1; another kind of descriptor or a non-descriptor will only be considered in step 3. (The official Python docs don't use the term "overriding descriptor"; they refer to a descriptor with `__set__` or `__delete__` as a "data descriptor", and if a data descriptor has `__get__`, the `__get__` will take priority over an object found in an instance dict.)

Comment: Thanks. What do "overriding" and "nonoverriding" mean when they qualify "descriptor"?

Comment: @Tim: They're just referring to whether it overrides a value found in the instance dict.

Comment: Thanks. (1) Is "either `__set__` or **`__delete__`** along with `__get__` would trigger it" mentioned in some documents?  (2) In " if a data descriptor has `__get__`, the `__get__` will take priority over an object found in an instance dict", do you mean `__set__` instead of `__get__`?

Comment: @Tim: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#invoking-descriptors, and no, I mean `__get__`.

Comment: Thanks. (2) When you wrote " if a data descriptor has `__get__`", I misread it as " if a descriptor has `__get__`". Doesn't a descriptor's class always have `__get__`? Why do you use "if"?

Comment: @Tim: It's unusual but permitted for a descriptor to have no `__get__`.

Comment: Can you provide a document to back up your comment? In Python in a Nutshell, "A  descriptor  is  any  object  whose  class  supplies  a  special  method  named  `__get__`".

Comment: @Tim: That line is wrong. Maybe they were glossing over things, or maybe they just weren't aware of all the little details, or maybe the error was introduced in editing or something.

Comment: From the same docs link: "In general, a descriptor is an object attribute with “binding behavior”, one whose attribute access has been overridden by methods in the descriptor protocol: `__get__()`, `__set__()`, and `__delete__()`. If **any** of those methods are defined for an object, it is said to be a descriptor."