# What is the lookup procedure when setting an attribute from a class or from an instance?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python in a Nutshell describes  [the lookup procedure when getting an attribute from a class, e.g. `cls.name` and the lookup procedure when getting an attribute from an instance, e.g. `obj.name`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44938264/156458)

But I am not sure when it comes to setting an attribute:

> **Setting an attribute**
>
> Note that the attribute lookup steps happen as just described only
>   when you refer to an attribute, not when you bind an attribute. When
>   you bind (on either a class or an instance) an attribute whose name is
>   not special (unless **a  `__setattr__`  method**, or **the  `__set__` 
>   method  of  an  overriding  descriptor**,  intercepts  the  binding  of 
>   an instance attribute), you affect only **the  `__dict__`  entry for the
>   attribute (in the class or instance, respectively)**. In other words,
>   for attribute binding, there is no lookup procedure involved, except
>   for the check for **overriding descriptors**.

My questions are:

- What is the "lookup" procedure when setting an attribute from a class, e.g. `cls.name=value`?
- What is the "lookup" procedure when setting an attribute from an object, e.g. `obj.name=value`?

The procedures seem to involve

- the `__setattr__`  method

  > **__setattr__(self, name, value)**
  >
  > At every request to bind attribute `x.y` (typically, an assignment statement
  >   `x.y=value`, but also, for example, `setattr(x, 'y', value)`), Python calls
  >   `x.__setattr__('y', value)`. Python always calls `__setattr__` for any
  >   attribute binding on x—a major diff erence from `__getattr__` (`__setattr__` is
  >   closer to `__getattribute__` in this sense). To avoid recursion, when
  >   `x.__setattr__` binds `x`’s attributes, it must modify `x.__dict__` directly (e.g.,
  >   via `x.__dict__[name]=value`); even better, `__setattr__` can delegate the
  >   setting to the superclass (by calling `super(C, x).__setattr__('y', value)`
  >   or, in v3, just `super().__setattr__('y', value)`). Python ignores the
  >   return value of `__setattr__`. If `__setattr__` is absent (i.e., inherited from
  >   `object`), and `C.y` is not an overriding descriptor, Python usually translates `x.y=z`
  >   into `x.__dict__['y']=z`.
- the  `__set__`  method  of  an  overriding  descriptor (So I asked  [Why does `object.__get__` have an argument `owner` for the owner class, while `object.__set__` doesn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44937813/156458))
- the  `__dict__`  entry for the attribute (in the class or instance, respectively)

[Given that the book distinguishes the lookup procedures for getting an attribute from a class and from an instance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44938264/156458), it is natural to think that the "lookup" procedures are different when setting an attribute from a class and when setting an attribute from an instance.

But since in Python3, every class object is actually an instance of its metaclass (e.g. `type` class), are the "lookup" procedure for setting an attribute from a class and the "lookup" procedure for setting an attribute from an instance really different?

Thanks.

Comment: Very simple: it assigns to that class's attribute. It doesn't go to the base classes.

Comment: The quote from the book doesn't seem so simple.

Comment: @Tim Your question is answered in the last sentence of your second quote: _"In other words, for attribute binding, there is no lookup procedure involved, except for the check for overriding descriptors."_.

Comment: I am not sure I understand that sentence, and I think that sentence can't replace the whote paragraph, because the paragraph implies there is still some "lookup" procedure, and that sentence also misses `__setattr__` method in the paragraph.  @ChristianDean

Comment: @Tim What's complicated about "you affect only the `__dict__` entry for the attribute"?

Comment: The parts I made in bold. @Barmar

Comment: Attribute retrieval goes through `__getattribute__` and `__getattr__` methods similar to `__setattr__` for setting. The resource you're reading doesn't seem to mention those, at least in the section you quoted.

Comment: @Tim Those are probably explained elsewhere. There's no generic description for them, because the overriding methods can do whatever they want.

Comment: @user2357112: For getting part, I updated https://stackoverflow.com/q/44913505/156458. For setting part, I will update my post here.

Comment: What edition are you reading?

Comment: 3ed in 2017 @user2357112

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `x.y = z`, Python looks up `x.__setattr__` in a way that bypasses `__getattribute__`, `__getattr__`, and `x`'s own `__dict__`, then calls `x.__setattr__('y', z)`.

A custom `__setattr__` can do whatever the heck it wants, but here's the default:

1. Search `type(x).__mro__` for a `__dict__` entry matching the attribute name.
2. If this search finds a descriptor `descr` with a `__set__` method (looking up `__set__` the same way we looked up `__setattr__`), call `descr.__set__(x, z)`.

   2.a. In the highly unusual case that the search finds a descriptor with `__delete__` but no `__set__`, raise an `AttributeError`.
3. Otherwise, set `x.__dict__['y'] = z`, or raise an `AttributeError` if `x` has no `__dict__`. (This uses the "real" `__dict__`, bypassing things like `mappingproxy`.)

This applies to both types and other objects, with the caveats that `type.__setattr__` will refuse to set attributes of a class written in C, and `type.__setattr__` does some extra internal maintenance you'll never need to worry about unless you do something crazy and unsupported to bypass it.

Comment: Thanks. (1) Does the first step mean that find a class in `type(x).__mro__` which has a class attribute named `y`? If yes and we find a class which can be an ancestry class of `type(x)`, why set the instance attribute `x.y` in `descr.__set__(x, z)` in step 2 and in `x.__dict__['y'] = z` in step 3, instead of setting the found class' class attribute `y`? (2) Does step 3 happen when the search in step 1 fails to find any class, or when the search in step 1 finds some class but the found attribute isn't a descriptor in step 2?

Comment: (3) if you can add some examples for each case, that will help to understand. (4) Is you reply based on some documents or the actual code implementation?

Comment: @Tim: 1) That's just how the language was designed. By default, setting an object's attribute is always an operation on that object, even if there's an existing class attribute. 2) Either.

Comment: Thanks. "By default, setting an object's attribute is always an operation on that object, even if there's an existing class attribute. " However, step 1 "Search `type(x).__mro__` for a `__dict__` entry matching the attribute name" seems to search for a class in `type(x).__mro__` which has `y` as its class attribute.  Maybe I misunderstand, so what does step 1 mean?

Comment: @Tim: It's looking for a descriptor to delegate the operation to, not an attribute to assign to.

Comment: Thanks.  how did you learn the procedure of setting attributes?

Comment: @Tim: Assorted docs, and I think a combination of experiment and checking the implementation to verify that descriptor handling was `__setattr__`'s responsibility instead of handled outside it somehow.

Comment: Thanks. In the book (see the quote in my post), it describes the setting procedure  "When you bind (on either a class or an instance) **an attribute whose name is not special** ". (1) Does a special name mean  any name which begins and ends with `__`? (2) When an attribute has a special name, what is the procedure of **setting** the attribute? (3) When an attribute has a special name, what is the procedure of **getting** the attribute?

Comment: @Tim: Which ones are "special" is entirely decided by the type and its implementation. My explanation applies to those attributes too; either they'll be handled specifically inside a custom `__setattr__`, or a descriptor will handle them. For example, assigning to an object's `__dict__` will either be special-cased by `__setattr__` or handled by a descriptor instead of going to a dict entry.

Comment: What is the rationale for the step 2.a (raising `AttributeError` if the class attribute is a *data* descriptor without the corresponding method) which exists only for `__set__` and `__delete__` but not for `__get__`?

Comment: (I have opened a new post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66754075/2326961) for this question, if you are interested.)