# Python property and variable assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

Below is a class from [this tutorial](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property) designed to demonstrate the functionality of the *property* in Python.

The class sets and gets temperature in Celsius and also converts to Fahrenheit:

```py
class Celsius:
    def __init__(self, current_temp = 25):
        self.temperature = current_temp

    def to_fahrenheit(self):
        return (self.temperature * 1.8) + 32

    def get_temperature(self):
        print("Getting value")
        return self._temperature

    def set_temperature(self, value):
        if value < -273:
            raise ValueError("Temperature below -273 is not possible")
        print("Setting value")
        self._temperature = 50

    temperature = property(get_temperature,set_temperature)
```

**Question**: Is it true that `self.temperature` (an *instance variable*) is actually referencing the *class variable* `temperature`? If so, then why?

Example:

```py
obj = Celsius()
print(obj._temperature, obj.temperature)
```

Returns:

```
Setting value
Getting value
50 50
```

I just don't understand how an instance variable with an assigned value (current_temp) could be actually referencing a class variable. Sorry if I have something mistaken.

Comment: Why does your setter unconditionally set `self._temperature` to `50`?

Comment: See [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-class-and-instance-variables-in-python-3) really nice blog about instance and class variables in Python. That should help you understand.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I wanted to demonstrate that `self.temperature` is set via the property and not via assignment during init. I just updated the example. Confused still...

Comment: "Is it true that self.temperature (an instance variable) is actually referencing the class variable temperature?" - referencing? No. The property object is involved, though. The "how" is the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors), but you don't have to dive into that to use properties.

Comment: It sounds like you've got a very specific idea about how attributes work, but attribute behavior is a lot more customizable than that. "Instance *variable*" isn't a great way to think about them - that implies a lot of things that aren't always true.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica "The property object is involved, though" - but how precisely? If you change the class var `temperature` to another name, then `self.temperature` is equal to 25 (because the property is not assigned). Does the class var `temperature` override the instance variable?

Comment: Python searches the class and all ancestors in method resolution order, looking for a descriptor for the attribute. It finds one (the property) and invokes the property's setter to handle the operation.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica "looking for a descriptor for the attribute. It finds one (the property)" - but *why* is the property (named `temperature`) a descriptor for `self.temperature`? I.e. if you assign the property a new name such as `NEW_NAME = property(get_temperature,set_temperature)`, then self.temperature is equal to 25 (and not 50). So Python must be assigning the descriptor to `self.temperature` based on name, yes? Thoughts?

Comment: "why is the property (named temperature) a descriptor for self.temperature?" *exactly because it has that name*. If you used `NEW_NAME` instead as the name, then you would be able to do things like `self.NEW_NAME = 30` and it would call `set_temperature`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it true that self.temperature (an instance variable) is actually referencing the class variable temperature?

You mean *attribute*, not variable. But yes.

> If so, then why?

Because instances of the class *do not have a `temperature` attribute* (they only have a `_temperature` attribute, and so after Python fails to find the attribute in the instance, it checks the class as well.

Perhaps you are being thrown off because the `__init__` method assigns to `self.temperature`. However, this does not create a `temperature` attribute on the instance, because the property is found first.

There are [complicated rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44938264/why-are-the-lookup-procedures-for-getting-an-attribute-from-a-class-and-from-an) for how the lookup of attributes works; they're designed to make it possible to do what you want - for example, to make it possible for `property` to work.

> I just don't understand how an instance variable with an assigned value (current_temp) could be actually referencing a class variable.

I don't see `current_temp` in your code, so I can't help with that.

---

Part of why the code is confusing is because it does things in a very non-standard way. [Normally](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property), `property` is used in its decorator form, which looks like this:

```
class Celsius:
    def __init__(self, current_temp = 25):
        # set the underlying value directly; don't use the property
        # although you *can*, but it's arguably clearer this way
        self._temperature = current_temp

    def to_fahrenheit(self):
        return (self.temperature * 1.8) + 32

    # the getter is given the name that the property should have.
    @property
    def temperature(self):
        print("Getting value")
        return self._temperature

    # The setter is "attached" to the getter with this syntax
    @temperature.setter
    # It doesn't matter that this has the same name, because of how the
    # internal attachment logic works.
    def temperature(self, value):
        if value < -273:
            raise ValueError("Temperature below -273 is not possible")
        print("Setting value")
        self._temperature = value # good idea to actually use the value!
```

Bonus: arguably, a better design is to have separate `celcius` and `fahrenheit` properties, and the ability to create an instance from either a celcius or fahrenheit value (use `staticmethod` to create factory methods). That looks like:

```
class Temperature:
    # Secret implementation detail: we store the value in celcius.
    # We could have chosen fahrenheit instead, and do the conversions
    # the other way around. Users should not call this directly.
    def __init__(self, c):
        # Actually, I lied. One good reason to use the property in
        # the init method is to enforce bounds checking.
        self.celcius = c

    # We offer factory methods that let the user be explicit about
    # how the initial value is provided.
    @staticmethod
    def in_celcius(c):
        return Temperature(c)

    @staticmethod
    def in_fahrenheit(f):
        return Temperature((f - 32) * 5/9)

    # Now we define properties that let us get and set the value
    # as either a celcius value or a fahrenheit one.
    @property
    def celcius(self):
        return self._celcius

    @celcius.setter
    def celcius(self, c):
        if c < -273:
            raise ValueError("below absolute zero")
        self._celcius = c

    @property
    def fahrenheit(self):
        return (self._celcius * 9/5) + 32

    @fahrenheit.setter
    def fahrenheit(self, f):
        # use the other property to reuse the bounds-checking logic.
        self.celcius = (f - 32) * 5/9
```

Comment: good answer! Three follow ups: 1) what's the difference between an instance *variable* and instance *attribute* (or class variable and class attribute)? 2) `current_temp` was a parameter to `init`. 3) "However, this does not create a temperature attribute on the instance, because the property is found first". Why is property found before `self.temperature` is assigned to `current_temp`?

Comment: 1. There are no "instance variables". In fact, `variable` is not really the best terminology for Python code in the first place; we have *names*, and attributes are a kind of name. For more details, try for example https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html . 2. Oops, glossed over that. Anyway, I hope the idea is clear. 3. See the link about lookup rules.